# RDLC Report - How to calculate Total Hours from Time in Hours:Minutes

Tags: sql, .net, reporting, rdlc, rdl

I am using RDLC Report. My requirement is, I need to calculate total Hours from values like
9:45
10:02

11:00

Main thing is it including blank values. So How I need to make equation for RDLC Report for getting total hours:minutes.

My current equation is as per below but it gives me #error :

```
=(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(IIf((Fields!TimeDiff.Value) = " " , System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"), System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)))).Days * 24 + 
TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(IIf((Fields!TimeDiff.Value) = " ", System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"), System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)))).Hours).ToString +":" + 
TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(IIf((Fields!TimeDiff.Value) = " ", System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"), System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)))).Minutes.ToString("d2")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(sum(Fields!TimeDiff.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for spending time to suggest way to me.